# How to make a simple GUI open another GUI and detect when it closes

Tags: java, user-interface

So im trying to create a simple GUI in which it has the option to enter multiple inputs. I want there to exist a main menu GUI and a input GUI. The question is, how can I make the main GUI disappear when "input" is selected, and reappear when "return to main menu" is selected?

Here is my main menu(unfinished)

```java
public class MainGUI extends JFrame{

    private JButton insert, find, browse, create;

    public MainGUI(String name) {

        super(name);


        setLayout(null);
        insert = new JButton("Insert");
        find = new JButton("Find");
        browse = new JButton("Browse");
        create = new JButton("Create Tree From File");

        insert.setBounds(25, 200, 100, 30);
        find.setBounds(125, 200, 100, 30);
        browse.setBounds(225, 200, 100, 30);
        create.setBounds(325, 200, 200, 30);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(insert);
        add(find);
        add(browse);
        add(create);

        insert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                //opens the input GUI window
                InputGUI input = new InputGUI("Input GUI");
                /*I was thinking of adding an if statement here, but it turns
                *out that the if statement executes immediately after the inputGUI is made...
                */

            }

        });

        //more action listener stuff here

    }
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        MainGUI gui = new MainGUI("Main Window");

    }

}
```

...and here is the input GUI class (unfinished)

```java
private JButton insert, ret;

    public InputGUI(String name) {

        super(name);


        setLayout(null);
        insert = new JButton("Insert");
        ret = new JButton("Return to Main Window");


        insert.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 30);
        ret.setBounds(150, 100, 200, 30);


        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(insert);
        add(ret);

        ret.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                String cmd = event.getActionCommand();
                if(cmd.contentEquals("Return to Main Window")) {
                    dispose();
                //how can i detect from the main menu gui that this was disposed?

                }

            }   
        });

        //more action listener stuff

    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        InputGUI gui = new InputGUI("Input Window");
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You might choose to override `dispose()` or `setVisible` method. This means you extend the `JFrame` class

Answer (score 0):

To make a window "disappear" without losing its content/data simply invoke `setVisible(false)` on the MainGUI object.

If you would like it to "reappear" run `gui.setVisible(true)` again.